# Italic font style not working in WebView for Google Fonts

Tags: android, html, css, fonts, webview

Using Google Fonts in a HTML file displayed via the WebView, if the font-style is set to italic, the font does not render italicised.

The same goes for the font-weight. Setting it to bold, the text renders normally.

This seems to only be the case for these custom fonts, with "system" fonts (e.g. Arial) rendering both bold and italic, when set.

I have pulled the files form the device using ADB and ran them locally, and in Chrome, they display correctly, both bold and italic.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the boxes for bold and italic when using Google Fonts. Otherwise you will only get one version. Go back to your fonts page on Google Fonts and check the desired styles and grab the new link.

Comment: I'm downloading them via Sky Fonts. It seems it only download the regular versions... Any idea how I get it to download the full font?

Comment: @MrPablo Sorry, never used Sky Fonts. Can't you use Google Fonts directly? https://www.google.com/fonts

Comment: I just checked and whilst the font doesn't state it supports bold or italic, I can set it to both via CSS. So there must be something up with the WebView?

Comment: @MrPablo CSS probably fallback to Regular if bold and italic doesn't exist. What is the name of the font?

Comment: "Just Another Hand". It seems that most browsers will "fake" the bold and italics, but not the Android WebView. What makes it worse is font-synthesis is not support by many browsers, so you cannot stop it from faking the look.